# How to create connecting lines between zoomed in subplot from another subplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I have a dataframe which looks as follows:
[image]

I have been able to create a zoom in subplot to depict values from 1990 to 2019 within a plot with values from 1990 to 2019. I'd like to add the connecting lines as shown by red color in the figure attached: [image]

The code I used to get the above image is as follows:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 12))
ax = df.plot(kind="area", stacked=True, ax=ax,
             color=colors)
ax.set_ylabel("TWh")
ax.set_title(
    "Global Energy Consumption from 1800 to 2019 \nSource: BP Statistical Review of World Energy 2021")
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))

# Create a plot for zooming in
# left, bottom, width, height
ax_new = fig.add_axes([0.4, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3])
ax_new = df.loc[1990:].plot(kind="area", stacked=True, ax=ax_new, color=colors)
ax_new.set_ylabel("TWh")
ax_new.set_title("1990 to 2019")
ax_new.legend("", frameon=False)

# plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("Global energy consumption", dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

How can I add connecting lines between the xaxes in two subplots?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/zoom_inset_axes.html Maybe will work for you?

Comment: Yep - specifically, the [`ax.indicate_inset_zoom(ax_new)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.indicate_inset_zoom.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.indicate_inset_zoom) method (which, fair warning, is experimental and subject to change)

Comment: ax.indicate_inset_zoom(ax_new, edgecolor="black", linewidth=4) did the job for me. However, I got connecting lines form y-axis rather than x-axis, which is still fine.